# Bison c code assignment

Tags: bison

If a loop structure is defined in *.y file as:

```
WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt ENDWHILE { //to be written here loop structure handling
- put WHILE into structure stack }
```

then - however I am forced to use ENDWHILE - how can I tie c code to ENDWHILE to check there is no overlap between structures?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Attached c code will be executed when the prescribed structure is found - i.e. at 'WHILE'. But how can I attach code to be executed when my program reaches 'ENDWHILE' ?

Comment: Actually, your code there will be executed when the whole thing has been found, including all of `WHILE`, `expr`, and `ENDWHILE`.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the braces in the example will only be executed when all the previous tokens and rules have been recognized (and any code executed).

If you have nested WHILE / ENDWHILE loops, the inner ones will be completed before the outer ones are.

Comment: So there is no need to check for any overlapping loops, Bison will handle it? I'm getting familiar with Bison and I have some gaps in my knowledge. Thank you for help.